# Link to show function with a table row

Tags: javascript, laravel

Please note, I am new to laravel and to programming in general.

I am trying to link to my show function in my OrderController to show my order by using a javascript function, but I am getting an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'" everytime I click on a table row and I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

**My orders.index view with my table and link to javascript function**

```
@extends('layouts/app')

@section('content')

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h4>Orders</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (count($orders) > 0)
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Recieved on</th>
                                <th>Customer</th>
                                <th>Worker</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    @foreach ($orders as $order)
                        <tr onclick="showOrder(order->$id)">
                                <td>#{{$order->id}}</td>
                                <td>{{$order->created_at}}</td>
                                <td>{{$order->customers->name}}</td>
                                <td>{{$order->users->name}}</td>
                                <td>${{$order->total_price}}</td>
                                <td><a href="/orders/{{$order->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></td> 
                                <td>
                                    <span class="table-remove">
                                         {!!Form::open(['action' =>['OrderController@destroy', $order->id], 'method' => 'POST'])!!}
                                            {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
                                            {{ Form::button('<i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm', 'type' => 'submit']) }}
                                        {!!Form::close()!!}
                                    </span>
                                </td>                               
                            </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    @if ($orderCount > 9)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$orders->links()}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endif
                </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@else
    <p>No orders found</p>

@endif

@endsection
```

**My javascript function**

```
function showOrder(id){
    window.location.replace("/orders/" + id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr onclick="showOrder(order->$id)">
```

this line should be  something like given below

```
<tr onclick="showOrder({{ $order->id }})">
```

Comment: Currently i am using mobile that is why i am  not able to giving you properly solution

Answer (score 0):

you can try it:

blade:

```
<tr onclick="showOrder({{ route('order.detail', $order->id) }})"></tr>
```

javascript:

```
function showOrder(url){
    window.location.replace(url);
}
```